# Unable to parse date

Tags: android, date, format

I am trying to parse following date in android to device local time.
The date is Thu Apr 07 18:26:42 GMT+05:30 2016 . I want to get this date in any other format, say MM-dd-yyyy.

Here is what I have tried :

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' Z yyyy", Locale.US);
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a");

        Date date = inputFormat.parse("Thu Apr 07 18:26:42 GMT+05:30 2016");
        String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
        WriteLog.Print("outputText" + outputText);
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. The above code is giving me exception saying unparseable date.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy` instead, for `inputFormat`? I have a feeling that the whitespace might be mismatching.

Comment: problem in your `inputFormat` section

Comment: @Knossos Thank you very much.
Yes whitespace was the problem.

Comment: Ill write that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your case is that you have a bit of whitespace in your `inputFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' Z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Instead you need to have:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy", Locale.US);
```